Vertex AI Studio typing issues
I can't use Vertex AI freely, because every time I write longer prompts, various syntax errors occur, and various errors appear so that the texts merge and "shake". This happens in all browsers.
(https://i.sstatic.net/QSiYXbDn.png)
I have tried to use all possible web browsers... chromium and non-chromium. I cannot report it, because I have no support from Google
